# Excessive "Failed to read module serial eeprom" on Catalyst 4507

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst

I have a plethora of these messages

```
%C4K_CHASSIS-3-LINECARDSEEPROMREADFAILED: Failed to read module 5's serial eeprom, try reinserting module
```

on my Cisco Catalyst 4507R. Thing is, there's nothing in that slot. Back in December I did insert a module into that slot, but `show module all` said the module wasn't supported, so I pulled it out a few minutes later. It appears these messages have posted regularly to my syslog server ever since. There is no clear interval between successive messages; I've seen a difference of four minutes to ten hours between messages.

How do I tell the chassis there's nothing in that slot? Also, if I do populate that slot with a module, do I have to do some sort of initialization? The module I tried installing was, I believe, a 48 port RJ45 module. If not that, it could've been a nine or 18 port GBIC module.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4507 supports module hot-swap, so there is no initialization needed: either the module is supported and it starts working, or it is declared as not supported.

The syslog messages you are seeing appear to be a software or hardware glitch of some sort and you have to ask Cisco for support.

If there is no other problem other than the syslog messages, I would suggest just ignoring them: they should go away when you reload or power cycle the switch some time in future.

If the syslog messages are too bothersome, you can try this procedure to see if they stop: insert another module in slot 5 and remove it after a few minutes. Use a module that you know for sure is supported.

Comment: I'll try that when I'm able to do a `reload`. There are too many cables in the way to do a hot-swap :)